# There is a unique solution $(a,b)$ of positive real numbers satisfying $a^p=b^q$ and $a^2+b^2=\epsilon^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations

Consider the holomorphic function $f(z,w)=z^p+w^q$ in two variables, where $p,q\geq 2$ are relatively prime integers. Let $V=f^{-1}(0)$, and consider the sphere $S_\epsilon=\{|z|^2+|w|^2=\epsilon^2\}$ centered at the origin, for small $\epsilon>0$. I am trying to show that $|z|$ and $|w|$ are constant functions for $(z,w)\in V\cap S_\epsilon$. This is equivalent to showing that there is a unique solution $(a,b)$ of positive real numbers satisfying $a^p=b^q$ and $a^2+b^2=\epsilon^2$. But I can't see this is true. How can we show this?

Comment: What is this for? This sounds like Milnor's Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces.

Comment: @TomKern Exactly. Milnor says that part is easy to show, but..

Comment: Because of the relation between $a,b$ it is obvious that $b$ hence $a^2+b^2$ increases with $a>0$ so the solution is unique, while it exists by continuity (when $a$ goes from $0$ to $1$ then $a^2+b^2$ must go through epsilon)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks I see.

Comment: happy to be of help